# OSX & glances: alert "ongoing memswap"

Tags: macos

My OSX is really slow sometimes during heavy development - normally I am using "glances" to find the suspect process.

No I experienced for the first time a warning like this:

```
 Warning or critical alerts (one entry)
2016-08-16 15:37:15       2016-08-16 15:31:58 (ongoing) - MEMSWAP (92.0)
```

with approx SWAP: 95% (total 7GB, used 7GB, free 450MB) - and used marked red.

The question is now: Is there any chance to find the reason or prevent this somehow?

Comment: You mean other than "buy more RAM" ?

Comment: I have 16GB and a lot of free around 5-6GB...